# Convert HDC to wxClientDC?

Tags: winapi, wxwidgets

Is there a way to convert a HDC to a wxDC object? I know wxDC is abstract. Is it possible to convert to wxClientDC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use semi-internal (and MSW-specific, obviously) `wxDCTemp` class, see `include/wx/msw/dc.h`.

Comment: What build trickery is required to get this class to be included? Do you include the msw version directly rather than wx.h or what? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you need to include `wx/msw/dc.h` directly. This is still (even more now) internal header, we probably need to extract this class into some public header to officially allow its use... I.e. don't be surprised if this doesn't work any longer in the future wx versions.